# insert multiple records in one go using a single insert into statement

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I want to insert multiple records in one go using a single insert into statement, but this format shows errors. Is this way correct?

Any other way to do it. Using oracle 11g

[Screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wivO4.png)

Comment: image of error I am currently recieving attached.. click on the question.

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php

Comment: You'll get a better response if you copy the text of your statement and the error into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT 1, 'Ralph', '2015-04-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Lamarr', '2015-03-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Jose', '2015-02-01' FROM dual;
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/78018/1)

Comment: Awesome! You should flag the answer as accepted. :)

Comment: @HarshitJuneja If this fully answered your question, you should use the upvote functionality and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

"INSERT ALL"statement you can use but still you have to construct every stm.

What is your final use case, if data are in a file then you can use external table.